# How can I get a list of all strings "greater" than a specific value in a List<string>?

Tags: c#, string, linq

Consider the following scenario.  I have a list of strings.

`var list = new List<string> { "Ringo", "John", "Paul", "George" };`

I need to sort the list and return ALL values after a specific value.  For instance, if the value I need to filter off of the name "George", I want to return:

`{ "John", "Paul", "Ringo" }`

Sorting using standard List methods or linq is simple enough, but since these are text strings, I'm drawing a blank on figuring out how to take all values *after* a specific filter since you can't us a greater-than sign in your where clause.

How can I do this.  Linq is preferable but not required.

Comment: Are you filtering George alphabetically, or positionally?  I.e. what does "after a specific value" mean in this context?

Comment: `>` cannot be applied to string.

Comment: @DStanley That is the exact code I'm try (just inside a linq expression) however this is the error: "Error CS0019 Operator '>' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'".

Comment: Ugh I've been away from C# for too long :) You are correct, and Dmitry has a great answer.

Comment: @JosephDoggie In short, I need to sort the list first (this gives 4 strings) then I want to filter out "George" and all values less than "George".  In this case there are no others.  If the name was "John", both "John" and "George" would need to be removed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can try querying with a help of *Linq* while using `StringComparer`:

```
  var list = new List<string> {"Ringo", "John", "Paul", "George" };

  string value = "George";

  var result = list
    .Where(item => StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase.Compare(item, value) > 0)
    .OrderBy(item => item)
    .ToList(); // if you want to get a list as an answer
```

Comment: i mistakenly edited and reverted.

Comment: Actually, this got me close to a sufficient answer.  Here is my **where** clause (although. yours is much more appropriate to a wider audience.) `from x in stringList where x.CompareTo(testString) > 0 select x`.

Comment: i don't think the query style is more *sufficient*, if you mean performance.

Comment: @RLH: that's perfectly OK providing that `stringList` doesn't contain `null` strings (in this case we'll have *exception thrown* on `x.CompareTo`)